# SQL Server Migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, migration, sql-server-2014, database-restore

I have a problem with my new instance database in SQL Server 2014, I installed SQL server 2014 and have restored all the databases I had in my instance of SQL Server 2012, but it seems that SQL Server 2014 is slower. Is this the correct way to migrate data?

An example of that is slower is that if I open SQL Server Management Studio 2014 and try to deploy the database tree of my instance and it takes around 3 minutes, mientrar SQL Server Management Studio 2012 takes 3 seconds.

I was researching on how to support databases and replace all compatibility mode to 120 which is the compatibility mode SQL Server 2014 but still just as slow.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much and regards

Comment: what is your database version? express, enterprise etc.

Comment: `try to deploy the database tree`???

Answer (score 0):

Backup/restore is common way to switch database to another instance. 
You mean connect to the instance is slower in new management studio? you need to run sql server Configuration Manager to enable all the server/client protocols such as Shared Memory/Namedpipe etc. 
If you are saying the database performance is slower after migrated to new instance. You need to do some migration work: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1936/sql-server-database-migration-checklist/